# Asp.Net website won't allow me to add reference class library. Already exists

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, dll

I'm trying to add a reference from my ASP.net website to my class lib. It's showing no reference currently but when I try and add it, it says it already exists. Looking in my properties page shows that one does exists, how can I remove the broken one?

### Trying to add

[image]

### Error when adding:

[image]

Comment: It's not added - you need to check the checkbox next to the name in Reference Manager

Comment: Well when this kind of stuff happens, you have two options `restart` or `clean solution then rebuild`.

Comment: When I open to add a reference it's not checked. I check it and hit add and that's when I get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in the Browse section.  Sounds like you've got a reference to the binary version of the component by the same name.

Comment: Thank you, I just deleted the old files in bin of the website and and added the reference again and it worked!